# C# programatically protect word document readonly at paragraph or range level

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

My tool will process more than 1000 docs.  We had set Readonly at document level, which leads to severe performance issue.
    _appObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document _DocObj;
    string file = @”c:\Users\Public\Public Documents\Word12.docx”;
    _DocObj = _appObject.Documents.Open(ref file, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref
     missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
    //protect
    appObject.ActiveDocument.Protect(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdProtectionType
      .wdAllowOnly Reading, ref noReset, ref password, ref useIRM, ref enforceStyleLock);

**But I want to  make the  Paragraph  or range to readonly**

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph aPar in 
                    _appObject.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range parRng = aPar.Range;
string sText = parRng.Text;
// I want to make readonly  here
}
```

Then the doc will get saved.

```
 _DocObj.SaveAs(FileName: TargetDir, FileFormat: WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);
            object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges;
            object originalFormat = WdOriginalFormat.wdOriginalDocumentFormat;
            object routeDocument = true;
            islockStatus = true;
 var doc_close = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)_DocObj;
 doc_close.Close(ref saveChanges, ref originalFormat, ref routeDocument);
```

Hence the requirement is like that to make a portion of word document (especially  HEADING or paragraph or alteast range)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Range` object, then you can use `Editors` member to access the list of users that are allowed to edit that range.

In your case, you would want to enable "everyone" to edit the entire document, then remove permission to edit specific paragraphs.

In VBA, this would look something like this (I'm sure you can translate this to C#):

```
' Allow access to the entire doc
ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone

' Remove access to paragraph 1
ActiveDocument.Content.Paragraphs(1).Editors(wdEditorEveryone).Delete
```